# TwentyThirteen theme Posts page shows posts instead of page content

Tags: posts, theme-twenty-thirteen

Under:

> Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays -> A static page -> Posts page

I can choose the name of a WordPress page from the drop-down menu.

How come WordPress takes the page title, displays the
page title in the menu on the front page, and then, when I click on the
page title I am shown the blog posts, instead of that page's content?

This makes me think pages are not suitable for use in this area as once
I designate a page as the posts page, its content becomes hidden and is
no longer visible. Could someone please explain why WordPress works in
this way?

The way the

> Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays -> A static page -> Front page

works on the other hand is clear. When the user goes to the URL corresponding to the
WordPress document root or clicks on the text in the header, WordPress displays this page.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can select a "posts page" is if you have **Front page displays** set to *a static page*. If you have **Front page displays** set to **your latest posts**, the dropdown selects for **Front page** and **Posts page** are *disabled*.

So, assuming you have **Front page displays** set to **a static page**:

- **Front page** is the page assigned to display on the site front page. This page's content is displayed if, per the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), the `page.php` template is used to render it. (That may or may not be true if `front-page.php` or a custom page template is used.)
- **Posts page** is the page assigned to display the **blog posts index**. It is **by design** that this page displays the main blog posts index, rather than the `post_content` of the page assigned as the posts page. The **Posts page** is a special page, that is assigned to this special use.

There are ways for this page's `post_content` to be displayed even when assigned as the **Posts page**, but the Theme would have to account for that explicitly, via the `home.php` template file, and direct query of `get_post( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) )`.